# OOP parent/child relationship using smart pointers

Tags: c++, oop, smart-pointers

I'm trying to learn how to use smart pointers efficiently and also working on programming in a more 'OOP' sense.

Basically the issue i've run into is the following:

```
// base class example
class class_a {
public:
    virtual void func( ) = 0;

    std::shared_ptr< class_a > m_parent;
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr< class_a > > m_children { };

    void add_child( std::shared_ptr< class_a > a ) {
        m_parent = this; // here! how could I go about this?
        m_children.emplace_back( a );
    }
};

// derived class example
class class_b : public class_a {
    int m_var { };

public:
    class_b( int param ) : m_var( param ) { }

    void func( ) override {
        // stuff
    }
};

/*
 * elsewhere
 */
auto parent = std::make_shared< class_b >( 14 );
{
    // class_c inherits 'class_a' like 'class_b'
    auto child = std::make_shared< class_c >( 6 );
    {
        // more children
    }
    parent->add_child( child );
}
```

regards.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do on the broken line, but a big issue you're *going* to have is that you've just made a structure full of circular references (which `std::shared_ptr` by itself can't defend you against). For stuff like this, you want `m_parent` to be a `std::weak_ptr`, so parents own children, and children only hold non-owning references to their parents (so when the top level parent is no longer owned, the whole tree is cleaned).

Comment: i'm attempting to (at some times) use the parent's base class variables (not shown in the example) inside it's derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to "connect" the new child to its parent.

Just assign a reference to the child internal variable then.

```
a->m_parent = this;
```

As others pointed, use a **weak_ptr** instead of shared pointer to hold the parent reference from your child(ren) otherwise on deletion of your parent node, the parent will still be maintained alive from the child instead of being garbage collected.

Comment: that's an option, however i'm trying to do it as 'OOP' as possible. so instead of manually assigning each and every parent per child control, the parent is assigned "automatically".

correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't using a weak_ptr be a poor idea if I'm trying to access the parent's (base class) variables?

thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: First, I don't get what/how "automatic" link could be created ? (would be good if you update your question by the way). Second, I am confused by your use of "parent" which can denominate either the base class or the parent container. Can you elaborate?

Comment: "garbage collected" ??

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, you have cycles in your storage hierarchy. For that case there is a primitive, called [`weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). Make your parent pointer as a `weak_ptr`.

Probably, you made a mistake in your code, I suggest to change `class_a` to this

```
class class_a : public std::enable_shared_from_this<class_a> {
public:
    virtual ~class_a() {} // Dont forget virtual destructor
  virtual void func() = 0;

  std::weak_ptr<class_a> m_parent; // must be weakly owning
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<class_a>> m_children{};

  void add_child(std::shared_ptr<class_a> a) {
    m_children.emplace_back(a);
    a->m_parent = shared_from_this(); // get a weak ptr from this
  }
};
```

Comment: That is a problem, but their code seems to include a completely different question (making `m_parent = this;` work, which makes no sense to me off-hand). I don't think they realize they're about to enter circular reference hell, because they haven't managed to get it working enough to encounter that problem.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't using a weak_ptr be a poor idea if I'm trying to access the parent's (base class) variables?

p.s getting the back of the container is unnecessary when I have the pointer as a parameter, is it not?

thanks for the help though.

Comment: @johntope You can use `weak_ptr` parent without locking all the time, unless, for example, you remove an element, without taking care of its children pointers, you concurrently remove, add, access elements elements, you must guarantee that the root of the tree is not destroyed, while you are using the tree elements, etc. Getting the back is not necessary, however a small safety thing in the ordering of the operations: if `emplace_back` throws and you handle somehow exceptions allowing the tree to be useful after it, then you are not having a parent pointer, that is not actually a parent.